# Sci-fi book with protagonist time travelling into a post-alien invasion future

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

I read this book around 2005, I think.

The main character is a scientist. Earth gets a message from aliens with blueprints for a portal/gate, and he helps build it. At the unveiling ceremony, however, the aliens come in guns blazing. The protagonist gets knocked out - and wakes up in an unfamiliar body, in a prison, with missing memories and remembering a very specific phrase.

It turns out he's years into the future, and the world was taken over by aliens. He ends up working with human resistance, of which I think his daughter was an important member, and the body he woke up in is his own grandson/grandnephew. I think there was a scene where somebody was killed with a syringe and an air bubble? Anyway, at the end of the book, in the aftermath of an attack by the resistance on some important alien facility, he's flung back in time to the portal unveiling ceremony, right before he woke up in the future, and realizes that he's stuck in a timeloop.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? I've been trying to track it down for ages.

Comment: What is the very specific phrase?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't remember it! It was something wordy and eloquent. I think what happened was that over the course of the adventure, the protagonist naturally thought of this phrase, and it was an early hint to the time loop nature of it.